# Dropdownlist disappears when mouse moves over hover

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a blog over at wordpress.com and there is a problem with the dropdown box on my main navigation.

When the mouse is hovering over, it appears, but when you move out of it to click a link its goes.

Heres the blog: https://readingartlab.wordpress.com/

Dropdown menu for 'Workshops'. This problem occurs when I added `margin-top: 11%;` so that it would align with the rule beneath it.

Any help? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

This is the CSS that has been changed:

```
.main-navigation ul ul {
    padding: 8px 0;
    margin-top: 11%;
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing anything amiss, except the links in the Workshops pulldown are dead.  Is that the issue? What do you mean by "when you move out of it to click a link it goes"? (Chrome/Mac)

Comment: You might want to list browser this is happening in.

Comment: Sorry just updated my changes. You should be able to see the problem now. I mean the dropdown menu dissapears before I can move my mouse over to it.

Comment: I am using Firefox on a mac

Comment: You need to share your code

Comment: Because this is wordpress.com on a theme, it only allows you to override any custom css you put, the original css can be seen if you inspect element on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a little padding to the bottom of your parent menu item 
`.menu-item-has-children > a {padding-bottom: 10px; margin-bottom: -10px; }`

If you target just those with a child item - .menu-item-has-children - it won't affect the other menu items. The negative margin-bottom offsets the expansion of the menu area that occurs with the adding of the padding-bottom. Using the > selector says, "Target the `<a>` elements that are a direct descendent just one level deep of the things with class `menu-item-has-children`." (So your extra padding won't affect the spacing / padding on your submenu.)

This is a great article about Child and Sibling Selectors in CSS - [CSS Tricks: Child and Sibling Selectors](https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/)

Answer (score 1):

So, the issue here is that there is a set amount of space devoted to your `.menu-item` -- when you hover over it, that triggers the submenu, but in order to move into the submenu, your mouse is actually leaving the space that triggers the hover effect. In Chrome Developer tools, when you click on the list item for Workshops in the HTML window, you see exactly how much space is around the list item:

[image]

Ideally, you'll reconfigure the CSS for that whole navigation area so there's more padding around the list item.

You can also try to trigger the `focus` class that the drop-down caret uses via jQuery, but that runs into some of the same problems and you end up either having to leave the submenu open until you click elsewhere or set it to remove on `mouseleave` of a larger parent element, like the header, which is pretty wonky.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I will give it try right now!

Answer (score 1):

You can't hover the margin of an element. Use padding or border instead to fill the gap between the parent en child element.

Have a look at this minimalistic demo on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brgwc0tq/).

```
ul.menu > li {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:5px;
}

ul.menu > li > ul {
  display:none;
  border-top:5px solid $navigation-background-color;
  margin:5px -5px -5px;
}
ul.menu > li:hover > ul {
  display:block;
}

ul.menu > li > ul > li {
  display:block;
  padding:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope these codes will solve the issue.

```
.site-header {
    border: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
.search-navigation {
    border-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 960px) {
    .search-navigation {
        margin-top: 30px;
        padding-top: 0;
        border-top: 1px solid #cecece;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #cecece;
    }
}
.main-navigation li {
    padding: 15px 0;
    border: 0 !important;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 960px) {
    .main-navigation .menu-item-has-children {
        padding-right: 0;
    }
}
.main-navigation .menu-item-has-children > a {
    padding-right: 38.5px;
}
.main-navigation a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 15px;
    border-right: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}
.main-navigation>div>ul>li:last-child a {
    border: 0;
}
```

It was happening because there was a gap between submenu and < li > which you are using for triggering hover.[visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLYw4.jpg)